# What is onModelReady and builder in ViewModelProvider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

The provider_arhitecture gives a widget ViewModelProvider which you can hookup with a ViewModel. The one thing I don't understand is what is the difference between the builder and the onModelReady like in this example here:

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return ViewModelProvider<HomeViewModel>.withConsumer(
  viewModelBuilder: () => HomeViewModel(),
  onModelReady: (model) => model.initialise(),
  builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        model.updateTitle();
      },
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text(model.title),
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs:

`onModelReady` fires the model after it is in ready state which is similar to  `initState` in stateful widget

*builder* is to build UI with the data stored in the model.

check the doc:

https://pub.dev/packages/stacked

https://pub.dev/packages/stacked#call-onmodelready-only-once

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).